# Mongoose: Set subdocument field value based on parent field value on save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is almost certainly covered elsewhere, but:

If I have a single schema with an embedded sub-document, like so:

```
var ChildSchema = new Schema ({
name : {
        type: String, 
        trim: true
},
user :{
    type: String, 
    trim: true
}
})

var ParentSchema = new Schema ({
name : {
     type: String,
     trim: true
},
child : [ChildSchema]
})
```

How would I save the name of the ParentSchema to ParentSchema.name and to ChildSchema.name in the same .save() action? The following does not work at all.

```
ChildSchema.pre('save', function(next){
this.name = ParentSchema.name;
next();
});
```

Comment: How are you connecting parents and children?

Comment: Also have a look at the [Mongoose Sub Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) examples.

Comment: Edited to show that the child schema is called and created within the parent schema. Still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by moving the middleware to `ParentSchema` which has access to itself and its children:

```
ParentSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var parent = this;
    this.child.forEach(function(child) {
        child.name = parent.name;
    });
    next();
});
```

Comment: `this` is `undefined` for me: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`